# trying to clip with gdal translate

Tags: python, gdal

I'm trying to clip a raster using gdal.Translate but i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mouqsit/Desktop/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    ds = gdal.Translate("C:\\wamp\\www\\Donnees_CRTS\\irrisat_dessimination-smiej\\new.tif", ds, projWin = [681483.831264, 3558183.87652, 747933.831264, 3607833.87652])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Translate'
```

This is my code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import sys ,os
output_dir='C:\\wamp\\www\\Donnees_CRTS\\irrisat_dessimination-smiej'
etp = os.path.join(output_dir,"L8_L8_ETpot_24_30m_2016_223.tif")
ds = gdal.Open(etp)
ds = gdal.Translate("C:\\wamp\\www\\Donnees_CRTS\\irrisat_dessimination-
smiej\\new.tif", ds, projWin = [681483.831264, 3558183.87652, 747933.831264, 
 3607833.87652])
ds = None
```

Have you any idea about what is happening right here?

Comment: What is your gdal version? You need GDAL > 2.1 to use `gdal.Translate`

Comment: I used gdal.2.2.0 but the same problem is occuring

Comment: What does `print gdal.VersionInfo()` return?

Comment: it returns this 1110200

Comment: `1110200` should be 1.11.2, if I'm not wrong... So you should update your Python GDAL bindings in order to make `gdal.Translate` work.